# Upper bound on the size of the maximum independent set

Tags: graph-theory

In [this assignment](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/5DA001/HT08/lab2.pdf) under chapter 3.7 the following formula is mentioned as an upper bound for the size of an maximum independent set in any given graph:
$$ |I_{max}| \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{1-8m-4n+4n^2}\right) $$

Where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges.

However the formula is not proven in any way in said text, which is why I ask how one would prove this?

Comment: Why won't you tell us what text that's from?

Comment: @bof I linked it under this assignment. Anyway: https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/5DA001/HT08/lab2.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let there be an independent set $I$ of cardinality $k$. Then there are at most  $\binom{n - k}{2}$ edges between vertices not from $I$ and at most $k(n - k)$ edges between vertex from $I$ and vertex not from $I$. But there is no edge between two vertices from $I$. Therefore
$$m \le \binom{n - k}{2} + k(n - k),\\
2m \le (n^2 - 2nk + k^2 - n + k) + 2(kn - k^2),\\
k^2 - k - (n^2 - n - 2m) \le 0,\\
D = 1 + 4n^2 - 4n - 8m,\\
\left(k - \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4n^2 - 4n - 8m}}2\right)\left(k - \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 4n^2 - 4n - 8m}}2\right)\le 0,\\
k \ge 0 \ge \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 4n^2 - 4n - 8m}}2 \land k \le \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4n^2 - 4n - 8m}}2.
$$

Comment: Oops, sorry! I didn't see your answer, you must have posted it while I was writing mine. (I am very slow.) I will delete my answer.