# Best known upper bound for the size of the maximum independent set in a given graph

Tags: graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for the tightest upper bound for the size of a maximum independent set in a general graph about which I know the size of nodes, edges, and the adjacency list. The only link I could find is [Upper bound on the size of the maximum independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296696/upper-bound-on-the-size-of-the-maximum-independent-set), however I was wondering if someone can point out a better source or potentially a tighter bound for me. or where should I do my research for this?

Comment: What do you mean by an upper bound for a *random* graph? We typically compute the expected value (or other properties of the distribution) of parameters in a random graph - a deterministic upper bound usually doesn't make sense here. Also, which random graph model are you using?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I meant a general graph. In other words, assuming that I have not any information whether the graph is a tree or planar or perfect etc. I am just trying to understand that if there's an upper bound that guarantees that there cannot exists a bigger independent set in that graph.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to remove the random-graphs tag, then, since it misled me. Do you have some parameters in mind, which you want to use in the upper bound? For example, the question you linked to has a bound in terms of the number of vertices and the number of edges, and it's the best we can say in terms of those two numbers alone - but if you know something else about the graph, then maybe you can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the accepted answer for the linked question, write $k$ for the maximum size of an independent set.  The given bound is
$$k\leq\frac12\left(1+\sqrt{1-8m-4n+4n^2}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt{(2n-1)^2-8m}\right)$$
or
$$(2k-1)^2\leq(2n-1)^2-8m$$
In a triangle, we have $n=m=3,\ k=1$ and the bound is tight.

Comment: The bound is tight (up to rounding) for any $m$ and $n$; take a graph with vertices $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ and add the first $m$ edges in the sequence $v_1v_2, v_1v_3, \dots, v_1v_n, v_2v_3, v_2v_4, \dots$ (that is, sorted first by the endpoint with the smaller index, then by the other endpoint). The largest independent set has exactly (floor of) this size.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I've been working on the question, for what $k$ do there exist $j,m$ so that a graph with these parameters exists and the bound is exact (without rounding) but I see I've messed up the algebra.